# Highlight Second Duplicates across multiple columns in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, countif

I'm trying to highlight only the duplicates (not the first instance) of various numbers across several rows. I'm about to do a large "action" where someone submits a form and I want google to automatically highlight any second, third, etc instances of a number. I've managed to get it this far, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

=and(countif(D$1:M1,D1)>1,countif(D$1:M1,D1)>1)

[What that formula looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQAW7.png)

As you can see, the second instance isn't always highlighted (1, 2, 4)

Comment: For your requirement, you want to compare only with the values before the current cell position. I may be wrong but I don't see a formula which when applied to a cell returns it's position which is what you'll need to apply a single conditional formatting formula to the entire range.
I suggest checking out apps script if you don't find a solution just by using sheets formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:M2,D2)>1
```

[image]

Comment: This might be an internal thing on my end because I put in the formula exactly and my final image looks nothing like the examples you gave. Thank you so much for reaching out, though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to search all previous rows for duplicates plus the current row as far as the current cell. If it's OK to include the headers in the range, you could try:

```
=countif($D$1:$M1,D2)+countif($D2:D2,D2)>1
```

[image]

Otherwise:

```
=ArrayFormula(countifs(row($D$2:$M2)+column($D$2:$M2)*0,"<"&row(),$D$2:$M2,D2)+countif($D2:D2,D2)>1)
```

[image]

Or simpler:

```
=if(row()=2,0,countif($D1:$M$2,D2))+countif($D2:D2,D2)>1
```

Comment: This might be an internal thing on my end because I put in those formulas exactly and my final image looks nothing like the examples you gave. Thank you so much for reaching out, though!

Comment: You're welcome. Plz check that the 'applies to' range is D2:M8. Actually can't see from the screenshot which rows your data is in but I assume the headers are in row 1 and data starts from row 2.

Comment: That is correct, yes. I'll look at the form again to double check that I put my range as such!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=countif($D:M,Indirect(Address(Row(),Column(),)))>1`